# List without gaps in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type, type-theory

How to define list of natural numbers without gaps in Coq?
For example `[2, 1, 3]` is valid list, but `[5, 1, 3]` is not because it have two gaps: between 1 and 3, 3 and 5.

I have try to ask Google, but nothing similar was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that a list of length `n` is without gaps iff its sorted version is equal to the list of naturals from 1 to `n`. If need be, this could be packaged in a dependent record, with the list and its no-gap property as fields.